# Why does adding images to the divs inside of my CSS grid make the grid too tall?

Tags: css, image, layout, css-grid

I have a simple web page with a header, a content section and a footer. My content section has uses css grid. I want the content to take up all of the space between the header and the footer with the header and footer always visible on the page. I find that with no images, this works. I can resize the screen and the footer is always visible.

However, after adding  tags within the grid divs, the footer is pushed off the page.
Here is a JS Fiddle with no images:
https://jsfiddle.net/7p3mbquk/

Here is a JS fiddle with images
https://jsfiddle.net/Lrm8gbue/4/
Notice how when you reduce the width of the screen, the footer gets pushed down below the window.

Brett Donald offered a solution below that works in chrome.
Why does it not work the same in Safari v14.1.2?
In this image, I have the site running in safari on the left hand side and Chrome v96.0 in the right hand side.
[image]

Here is my CSS...

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 99vh;
}
.header {
  flex-basis: 10px;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  flex-basis: 10px;
  grid-area: footer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  flex-basis: 1 0 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  align-self: top;
  grid-area: content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.content .description {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
  font-family: verdana;
  /* text-shadow: 2px 2px white; */
  padding: 1rem;
}

.oval {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px / 100px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px white;
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
}
.content > .photos {
  flex-grow: 4;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .content > .photos {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content > .photos {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
.content > .photos > div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content > .photos img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Here is my markdown

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
  <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <p class="coname">Momo's Surf School</p>
      <p class="contact">Contact</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="oval">
        <div class="description">
          Make your holiday amazing with a fun, relaxing day learning to surf
          with Mo!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="photos">
        <div><img src="./assets/woman.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/women.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/man.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/woman3.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/woman2.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/waves.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/twoBoys.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="./assets/barrel.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><p>Established 2013</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content div needs an `overflow-y: scroll;` rule. And I got rid of your flex-basis rules.

Is this the effect you are after?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.content {
  align-self: top;
  grid-area: content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content .description {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
  font-family: verdana;
  /* text-shadow: 2px 2px white; */
  padding: 1rem;
}

.oval {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px / 100px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px white;
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
}
.content > .photos {
  flex-grow: 4;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .content > .photos {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content > .photos {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
.content > .photos > div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 0;
}
.content > .photos img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <p class="coname">Momo's Surf School</p>
      <p class="contact">Contact</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="oval">
        <div class="description">
          Make your holiday amazing with a fun, relaxing day learning to surf
          with Mo!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="photos">
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443181994330-3e365ff8949e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YmVhY2h8ZW58MHwyfDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><p>Established 2013</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Exactly, but with overflow-y: hidden. Thank you.

Comment: Why does this not work the same in Safari? I have edited my question to include a screenshot contrasting the outcome in Safari vs Chrome.

Comment: Works fine for me in both Safari and Chrome. And even in your screen shots, the header and footer are both visible. The issue you're having in Safari isn't related to your original question, so probably better to post it as a new question, AFTER you have reduced it to a minimal example.

Comment: I notice that on mobile, there are 3 columns of photos. I imagine this means that there are between 700 and 800 pixels in my mobile device. But I want the phone to only show 2 columns of photos. I am confused because I thought that media queries work based on "CSS pixels" and not actual physical pixels in the device.

Comment: I am also confused because in Chrome's developer tools inspection tab, if I choose to simulate the mobile device view, the content looks different than when I open the site on an actual mobile device.